# Обособляется ли оборот с "благодаря"?

Tags: пунктуация, предлоги

**Таким образом, благодаря использованию автором большого количества прилагательных, намного ярче представляется описанная картина.**

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае обособление оборота с предлогом ***благодаря*** является ***факультативным***. В пользу его обособления можно сказать, что оборот  **распространённый** и **находится не в начале и не в конце предложения**.

Таким образом, ***благодаря использованию автором большого количества прилагательных***, намного ярче представляется описанная картина.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1